# Should we "Burninate" the [stack-exchange] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, meta

The [Stack Apps topic help](https://stackapps.com/help/on-topic) makes it clear that ***all*** questions here must pertain to Stack Exchange in some way:

> If your question is about …
>
> - the **Stack Exchange** API
> - applications built on the **Stack Exchange** API
> - scripts or browser extensions that work with **Stack Exchange** sites
>
> … it is welcome here.
>
> Please look around to see if your question has been asked before. It’s
>   also OK to ask and answer your own question. ...

<sup><sup>(Emphasis added)</sup></sup>

Meanwhile the [stack-exchange](/questions/tagged/stack-exchange) tag has [24 questions](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange?sort=votes) and no tag wiki.

Looking at the current questions, it seems to me that [stack-exchange](/questions/tagged/stack-exchange) adds no value to those questions.
Compare to related tags like [stackapps](/questions/tagged/stackapps), [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow), [network-profile](/questions/tagged/network-profile)<sup>(not yet needed here but used on *Meta Stack Exchange*)</sup> -- which potentially can be used for Searching/Filtering/Classifying questions in a useful way.

So, should we remove the [stack-exchange](/questions/tagged/stack-exchange) tag?

If you say no, then please also suggest a useful tag excerpt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on a reasonable response for Stack Apps, this has now been done.

Merged [stack-exchange](/questions/tagged/stack-exchange) into [support](/questions/tagged/support) (which many of the questions already had) and deleted [support](/questions/tagged/support) from those posts where it didn't apply.

These 24 questions were affected:
    [2332](//stackapps.com/q/2332/expose-the-contents-of-the-accounts-tab-of-the-se-network-profile-as-machine-r),
[2371](//stackapps.com/q/2371/add-timeline-and-revisions-links),
[2372](//stackapps.com/q/2372/unhide-the-ignored-tags-hider),
[2373](//stackapps.com/q/2373/add-draft-save-links),
[3045](//stackapps.com/q/3045/creating-a-php-script-to-use-the-stack-api),
[3136](//stackapps.com/q/3136/hot-questions-network),
[3408](//stackapps.com/q/3408/stack-exchange-deleted-answer-manager),
[4457](//stackapps.com/q/4457/does-stackoverflow-track-what-specific-user-is-searching-for),
[4617](//stackapps.com/q/4617/is-there-support-for-unicoins-in-the-stackexchange-api),
[4699](//stackapps.com/q/4699/how-to-make-a-stack-exchange-api-call-using-my-key),
[4888](//stackapps.com/q/4888/filter-se-questions-by-votes-views-and-rep),
[4942](//stackapps.com/q/4942/stackoverflow-call-returning-some-zipped-data-when-i-call-from-server-side),
    
[6155](//stackapps.com/q/6155/wstack-stack-exchange-app-for-windows-phone-8-1),
[6189](//stackapps.com/q/6189/fetch-the-personalized-prediction-data-through-the-api),
[6652](//stackapps.com/q/6652/hide-the-stack-exchange-sidebar),
[6716](//stackapps.com/q/6716/when-asking-answering-a-question-on-se-sites-is-there-a-way-to-fix-the-page-in),
[6771](//stackapps.com/q/6771/review-tag-repositioner),
[6773](//stackapps.com/q/6773/flagging-percentages),
[7242](//stackapps.com/q/7242/top-pagination-for-user-reputation-league),
[7445](//stackapps.com/q/7445/clone-the-tags-in-questions-page-if-the-tags-are-not-visible-in-the-initial-win),
[7679](//stackapps.com/q/7679/where-could-i-get-the-eer-diagram-of-stackexchange-com),
[7833](//stackapps.com/q/7833/stackcrunch-a-platform-to-share-your-development-experiences),
[7946](//stackapps.com/q/7946/stackexchange-hot-network-questions-page-icon-size-fix),
[8264](//stackapps.com/q/8264/how-to-search-all-sites-with-the-advanced-api).

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  I would agree that the tag serves no purpose.

With only 24 questions, let us lose it.